# How to get the innerHTML of nested nodes

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me how I can get the innerHTML of the first `td` `a` anchor? I cannot seem to get this right. What I'm looking for is the "test 1" and "test 2" values.

```
<tr>
  <td data-pid="2"><a data-pid="2" href="#"><a href="#">test 1</a></td>
  <td><a data-pid="2" class="manage-icon" href="#"><img alt="" src="delete.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-pid="3"><a data-pid="3" href="#">test 2</a></td>
  <td><a data-pid="3" class="manage-icon" href="#"><img alt="" src="delete.png"></a></td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:
Sorry for not explaining the event. I need the innerHTML for the row I click on. So, if I click on row 33 and its value is "test 33", that's what I need to see.

I'm using a click function:

```
$(document).on("click",".manage",function(e){...
```

Comment: On what event, in response to *what*? Do you want both `test1` *and* `test2` in every occurence, and as a string or as an array? When you say you 'cannot seem to get this right,' can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, assuming you're clicking on the image (if you want to trigger on the link instead, just change `img` to `a`):

```
$('img').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('a').html());
});
```

However your HTML has an error (unclosed anchor).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sjWzm/2/)**

Comment: That's returning the value for the first row and not the second which is the one I clicked on

Comment: Updated to be relative to the image or link clicked on.

Comment: Thanks, J. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    var aText = $(this).find('td:first-child a').html();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7tvkK/).

Note that, in the demo, I *have* edited the HTML of the first row's elements to match the format of the second row's first `td`'s elements (the extra `a` opening tag seemed to be an error, but if it was deliberate then the jQuery can be amended).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Prefer chained find calls over multi-element queries (i.e. use `$(this).find("td:first-child").find("a")` instead of `$(this).find("td:first-child a")`) as they run faster.

Comment: Dave, what exactly is `this` referencing?

Comment: `this` is the DOM node identified by the jQuery selector (`$('tr')`), `$(this)` is the same DOM node, but wrapped in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

To get innerHtml value that is you mentioned test1 , test2 you can use `.text()` function like this

```
$('td a').text();
```

If you want to take first-child of td then you could do this: `$('td:first-child a').text();`

Answer (score 0):

For *values* I think you mean the `text`
BTW You have an error in this line:

```
<td data-pid="2"><a data-pid="2" href="#"><a href="#">test 1</a></td>
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ extra
```

and than this might help: **[*LIVE DEMO*](http://jsbin.com/abORava/1/edit)**

```
$('table tr').click(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();                 // prevent unwanted anchor click behavior
  var txt = $('td a', this).text();   // use .html() if you need to  
  alert( txt );                       // Test text value
});
```

if you **populate dynamically** your table **rows**, than go with:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function( e ){
```

Comment: Thank you Roko for the answer. I'm going to try this anyhow and see if it works. I'm still trying to learn my way around JQ

Comment: It's weird because I get nothing back with your code. What does work though is: `$(this).closest('tr').find('a').html();`